# SNMP can't find the OID in the OID Tree

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I installed net-snmp on centos 7 with yum :

```
yum install net-snmp
```

I configured the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file to see all the oid tree :

```
#Make at least  snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public system fast again.
#       name           incl/excl     subtree         mask(optional)
#view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
#view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
view    all     included        .1      80
```

when i tap the snmpwalk command :

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1
```

it works , but i want to search a specefic oid which is :

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.8711.101.28.1.2.7.20.40.30.10
```

the snmpwalk doesn't return a result .

how can i add this oid to the oid tree ??

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [IANA's PEN registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers) you see that the private enterprise number 8711 is registered to 'THALES Broadcast & Multimedia'. You installed net-snmpd which doesn't have a subagent registered under this number in it's default configuration.

Since this company seems to be selling IPTV products (I only did a very quick search, no real research) I assume you actually want to query some parameters on the device itself; you don't need a snmp-daemon running on a different machine. Try querying the real target machine instead.

However, if your vendor really provided you with a subagent which shall be installed on your Linux machine, you need to tell net-snmpd to pass all queries to the vendor OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.8711` to this agent. The configuration methodes depends on the type of subagent; if it's AgentX extension configure the `master agentx` statement and start your subagent after restarting snmpd. If it's just a simple script, you should read up on the [EXTENDING AGENT FUNCTIONALITY section](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) in the manual. There are many ways to accomplish this.

Extra-note: The OID you're querying is already deep down the vendor tree. Many subtrees are dynamic and depend on the actual hardware configuration. Try an snmpwalk higher up the tree. I suggest starting directly at `1.3.6.1.4.1.8711`. However, it won't work on that certain net-snmp your configured anyway.